# Read file from Spring based web application

Tags: spring, web-applications, file-read

I am developing a Spring based JMS application which will be deployed as a web application. It has no servlet part except the web.xml with listener which loads the Spring context. When JMS listener receive a message, I need to read a resource file to get the reply message. But I am not sure where to put the resource file inside web app and how to specify the file path in the Java command which reads the file. Can somebody explain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but I suggest you read up on the chapter of the Spring reference manual on [I/O Resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html). Spring provides a very nice `Resource` abstraction for doing this sort of thing.

How you choose to use it, though, is up to you. I can't further advise you based on the information you've given us.